# apple sandbox test user account?

Tags: app-store, sandbox

I tried to created a test user for my IAP app for testing.  Apple ask for the real credit card number in order to login the test user to apple store.   I am afraid that apple store will charge me by chance while I do my testing.

Do you have to provide real credit card number for sandbox user?

Comment: I just went through my old questions here.  The answer should be you don't login to apple store from settings.  Login to test account when you do in-app-purchase from the app.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

No you dont.

Log out by going through: Settings -> Store

Do **NOT** login with your test user. (Otherwise you get that credit card screen).

Instead run your app and login with the test user when asked to.

Note: If you have already logged in with your test user it will become invalid. So in your case you will need to create a fresh test user and only log in when prompted to do so by your app.

Comment: By "it will become invalid," do you mean the test user account will become invalid?

Comment: @ThunderRabbit _"**Important**: Do not enter your test account information in the Store settings panel. Doing so may invalidate your test account."_ [Source: Apple Docs - Testing Your In-App Purchases](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/13_ManagingIn-AppPurchases/ManagingIn-AppPurchases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH4-SW3)

Comment: It seems that at least the account doesn't become invalid anymore when you try to login in the App Store. Still this is vital information for anybody testing IAP.

Comment: Save much time!! Very disappointing thing by Apple.Additionally they does not mention anywhere

Comment: It is mentioned here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH25-SW9

Comment: Thank you for this.  After 2 days of banging my head against a wall, this is what got me to a successful transaction.

Comment: On my first time trying to test I got the in app sign in password wrong (I think). The flow then took me on to a full store sign in and I knew no better and promptly burned my sandbox user. Don't do it-it's a trap!

Comment: Thank you very much. The official docs add to confusion by saying  "[...create your test user and then...] Sign out of your Apple ID on all testing devices and SIGN BACK IN WITH YOUR NEW SANDBOX TESTER ACCOUNT" (caps are mine), at https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/ . Your answer cleared everything up, and it worked for me. Thanks!