# iOS 13 - How to login in in-app purchase Sandbox account?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ios13, appstore-sandbox

In order to test my in-app purchases with iOS 13 I have to update one of my test devices to iOS 13.1 beta.

On iOS 12 and before there was a special Sandbox login in `Settings/iTunes & App Store/Sandbox Account`:

[image]

However, after the update to iOS 13 this section is missing. I tried to follow the [instruction in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53196544/777861) to a similar problem on iOS 12 but nothing worked. I completely reset the device and logged out both at `Settings/iTunes & App Store` and at `Settings/Apple ID`, so currently the device is not connected to any account (real or sandbox). At least as far as I can tell.

I have re-installed my app on the devices using Xcode 11 beta and tried to perform an in-app purchase. **The store shows a login prompt which shows that this is a Sandbox purchase. However, the prompt only asks for the password, not for a username or Apple ID.** So I have no idea which account should be used here.

When using the password of a newly created test user account the password is not known. I can use the password of my real Apple ID account which was used during the device setup and was then disconnected.

**So, how to connect to a specific Sandbox account in iOS 13?**

Answer (score 31):

Here's what worked for me (on a dedicated development iPhone 6s running iOS 13.3).

1. Sign out of *iTunes & App Stores*
2. Sign out of *iCloud*
3. Run app on device, and click to purchase an item.
4. When prompted for an ID/Password, enter the Sandbox Tester credentials.

It took entering the credentials a couple of times, but the In App purchase dialog alert did say the environment was Sandbox.

After it "made good" (that is, stopped asking me to log in and processed the *SKPaymentTransation*), I was able to go to *iTunes & App Stores* in the General Settings, scrolled to the bottom, and now the Sandbox Account appears with the tester account showing.

Now when I run the app and click the button to purchase content, it just asks for the tester password.

Hopefully this helps others.

Comment: Worked as described. This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: This worked for me as well, except it's under App Store, at the bottom. Clicking the sandbox email opens a prompt to manage subscriptions and be able to cancel / make the account eligible again.

Comment: KEEP SCROLLING, there's an answer for iOS 14+ below. I wonder why SO isn't prepared for such changes. Outdated answers should go down.

Answer (score 29):

**Sandbox Account** section, in the *iTunes & App Store* of iOS 13, is not visible right away and can be confusing. Here is how to enable it:

1. Navigate to Settings.app → iTunes & App Store
2. Log in with your **developer account (non-sandbox)** on top of the screen where it says "Sign In..."
3. Ignore rest of the screen for now and go to your app.
4. Make an In-App Purchase.
5. iOS will ask you for an email and password to complete the purchase.
6. Enter **sandbox user credentials** in the alert form.
7. In-App Purchase will proceed with [compressed sandbox times](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev7e89e149d).
8. Go to iTunes & App Store again. At the very bottom, you will see the new **Sandbox Account** section. You can logout and login to a different sandbox account or leave it as is.

---

You can't enter the sandbox account into iTunes & App Store as the **primary account** as of iOS 13 — the system will refuse to log you in with error with an odd copy mentioning "try again later." No matter how much you wait, iOS 13 will refuse your sandbox account here.

Comment: There is no such thing as "iTunes & App Store" on iOS 14. There is an "App Store" ONLY.

Comment: How we can make an in-app purchases ( for the first time) w/o a sandbox account.

Answer (score 19):

### iOS 14, iOS 15, iOS 16

> In iOS 14 the Settings panel changed slightly. Sandbox sign in is
> no longer in Settings->AppleID->iTunes & App Store.
>
> In Settings, scroll down a bit and you'll see App Store >, just above
> Wallet & Apple Pay. The Sandbox sign in is now located in the App
> Store menu.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661730

Edit by Konstantin Kozirev:

> In iOS and iPadOS, the sandbox account appears in Settings > App Store after the first time you use the device to attempt a purchase in a development-signed app.

Comment: This answer should be displayed on the top.

Comment: Please, complete the answer with this part: `In iOS and iPadOS, the sandbox account appears in Settings > App Store after the first time you use the device to attempt a purchase in a development-signed app.`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and i finally found the solution : 
You just try to purchase the product in your app and enter your sandbox user credentials then you will get the Settings/iTunes & App Store/Sandbox Account login.

Answer (score 6):

The following worked for me on ios 13:

Settings -> iTunes & App Store -> Scroll all the way down and click on "Sign In" under the "SANDBOX ACCOUNT" section

Comment: Now just App Store, not iTunes & App Store.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue looking for a solution than I found this article, [in-app purchase testing](http://help.testlio.com/en/articles/464611-testing-in-app-purchases-on-ios)

I think from ios 13 and onward, we don't require a sandbox user for in-app purchase testing neither for dev nor prod.

[image]

Comment: TestFlight users are **real** users with **real** App Store accounts which have access to beta builds. This is something different than Sandbox users. Once a user has purchased an IAP item this purchase is linked to the users account for ever. Being able to switch between different Sandbox App Store accounts is essential to test different IAP scenarios (new, returning users, etc.) especially when working with subscriptions. A **real** TestFlight users who has purchased your subscription/IAP once can never impersonate a new user again.

Comment: The caveat here is, you can't reset purchase history for a real Apple account used in test flight builds... whereas you could/can with a sandbox test account.

Answer (score 4):

It seems iOS bug, I had the same issue, And i was able to see SANDBOX ACCOUNT section only after doing these steps:

1. Sign out with my production apple id.
2. Sign in with the sandbox account apple id.
3. Sign out with the sandbox account apple id.
4. Sign in with my production apple id.

Afterwards you will be able to see your production apple id in use and the test apple id in SANDBOX ACCOUNT section.

Comment: Thanks but this did not work for me. I tried several times but it had no effect. I can sign in and out at two different places: `Settings/Apple ID` and `Settings/iTunes & App Store` and tried different combinations. The result is always the same: No sandbox accout section in settings

Comment: I had the same issue , do as Shady says : 
You just try to purchase the product in your app and enter your sandbox user credentials then you will get the Settings/iTunes & App Store/Sandbox Account prompt. but it silently fails, but when you try again, it will say [Sandbox] from there onwards and work after that.  (iOS 19.1.1) Using that credential to sign into the store will break the credential.

Answer (score 2):

## iOS 16+

To let the Sandbox account appear in the **`Setting -> AppStore -> Sandbox`** you first need to add the sandbox email and password in **`App Store Connect -> Users and Access -> Sandbox`** then from your Xcode run your app (the test purchase code) on your device and try to purchase, it will ask you for Apple ID and password insert your sandbox email and password that you entered in the App Store Connect and complete the purchase test successfully. Now, after you have completed your first test purchase successfully, you can go to your device **`Setting -> AppStore -> Sandbox`**  you will see the sandbox account did appear.

Comment: I can confirm this answer works in iOS 16

Answer (score 1):

Install your app with in-app purchases via TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

While unfortunately none of the suggested answers helped to actively bring back the Sandbox option, in my case it helped to update to the (now) latest iOS 13 version.

I do not know if this just a coincidence, if there was some bug fix in the latest iOS update or if I have performed any *healing steps* without knowing it...

So, while this is no real solution I added this answer just in case it might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

alright, this works for me. Similar to @Tim in the first answer.

So you have to log out your primary Apple ID for iCloud. Then you just run your test app, click the button where you wanna trigger in-app purchase. It will ask you for email and password to login.

You login, then if you go back to your iTunes and Appstore, you will see the sandbox account you just signed in just list there.

You can then log out, and log in other sandbox account. yay~