# iTunes Sandbox account keeps on asking for password for a non-signed in account

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have IAP in my application. I haven't logged in to any sandbox account under iTunes & App Store section in Settings. But whenever an IAP transaction starts in my app, the OS asks for a password(**Only password and not Sandbox ID**) like it already has the sandbox details somewhere  and when I enter the password for a non-logged in account, it logs in without asking the ID. Where does OS get the sandbox account details from? I am confused.

Comment: The password prompt appears only when you trigger the purchase of an IAP? If so, have you tried re-installing the app?

Comment: Yes, the prompt appears when I trigger the IAP. I have also tried reinstalling the app. Still it prompts only for password

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 13 - How to login in in-app purchase Sandbox account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850713/ios-13-how-to-login-in-in-app-purchase-sandbox-account)