# How do i test In-App-Purchase using Sandbox account in ios below 12

Tags: ios, react-native, testing, in-app-purchase, expo

In my react-native-app with expo am trying to implement expo-in-app-purchases("https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/").I did all setup mentioned in the document.next am trying to build the solution with Xcode and my device.The build always failed with this message:

```
 node_modules/@hapi/hoek/lib/assert.js:20
 throw new AssertError(args);
^

Error: Method no longer accepts array arguments: try
at new module.exports (/Users/Projects/test/node_modules/@hapi/hoek/lib/error.js:23:19)
at module.exports (/Users/Projects/test/node_modules/@hapi/hoek/lib/assert.js:20:11)
at Object.exports.verifyFlat (/Users/Projects/test/node_modules/@hapi/joi/lib/common.js:211:9)
at internals.Base.method [as try] (/Users/Projects/test/node_modules/@hapi/joi/lib/types/alternatives.js:168:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Projects/test/node_modules/react- 
native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/config/schema.js:35:36)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

am using ios device version 10.3.3(it's ipad).am also trying to configure my sandbox account in this device,but there is no option to set sandbox account.in settings->iTunes&Appstore it only showing automatic downloads nothing else.Like this:
[image]

My sandbox Account:
[image]

What should i do?

UPDATE:
In my iOs phone(14.2) also unable to view the sandbox account why?any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a test user in appstore-connect, or implement a storekit file.

Comment: I have test user account in my appStore connect.am trying to add the same in my device but i can't see any option there.

Comment: try to under App Store / Sandbox user

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to solve your build issue in expo, but to utilize a sandbox purchasing test account the best method is still to "sign out" of all iTunes & app store accounts (some suggest singing out of iCloud as well) then just initiate the purchase in the application.

The OS will prompt you to sign in with an iTunes account. This is where you input your test account credentials.

This method works on all iOS versions.

Note: You should not use sandbox accounts on apps downloaded from the app store. Only use sandbox accounts on builds "pre-release"

Comment: There is also some good info in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850713/ios-13-how-to-login-in-in-app-purchase-sandbox-account