Sandbox account does not appear in the app store section in settings
I entered Setting > App store section. But ı cannot see anything about sandbox account. What should ı do?
Note: I have a sandbox app installed on the dev from Xcode.
I tried everything possible ı can :/ . Can someone help please?
I must see sandbox account part in Setting > App store section but it doesn't appear.

waiting for up to 48h usually fixes such issues. die the user appear in appstore-connect?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70354507/5790492

To resolve the issue, try making a sandbox purchase. You should enter your login and password in the alert that appears. After that, the Sandbox account section will show up in the settings.

What if no alert is shown when tapping on the buy button?
I have my personal iPhone with latest iOS 18 and logged in with my personal icloud account. After installing the app from xcode and trying to make a purchase, only sheet with the Purchase button is shown and if I press Purchase, the product is being purchased in xcode environment. There is no alert to login in.

Same here, did you fix that? @RobertBasamac

@RyanHoo, yes, I solved it.  I assume you are using a local .storekit file in your scheme. In order to use sandbox environment you have to not use any .storekit file at all.  Using local .storekit files that mirror (or not) the App Store Connect configuration will use the xcode environment.
So go in xcode, Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme->Run (left side menu)->Options and select "None" as Storekit configuration.
Let me know it worked.
