# How to add sandbox account in iOS 16.6?

Tags: ios, in-app-subscription, appstore-sandbox

I have added in-app subscription in App Store Connect and also sandbox user but I am unable to find a setting to add the sandbox account in my iPhone 12 Pro Max (iOS 16.6).

I have added some time before for the `Setting->AppStore-> Sandbox`

I have readed these questions but the option is not there.

[iOS 12 IAP Sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087001/ios-12-iap-sandbox)

[Apple sandbox user logout before production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668336/apple-sandbox-user-logout-before-production)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 13 - How to login in in-app purchase Sandbox account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850713/ios-13-how-to-login-in-in-app-purchase-sandbox-account)

Answer (score 0):

To let the Sandbox account appear in the **`Setting -> AppStore -> Sandbox`** you first need to add the sandbox email and password in **`App Store Connect -> Users and Access -> Sandbox`** then from your Xcode run your app (the test purchase code) on your device and try to purchase, it will ask you for Apple ID and password insert your sandbox email and password that you entered in the App Store Connect and complete the purchase test successfully. Now, after you have completed your first test purchase successfully, you can go to your device **`Setting -> AppStore -> Sandbox`** and you will see the sandbox account did appear.

Comment: Please [do not post the same answer to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Instead, flag the this question as a duplicate of [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850713/ios-13-how-to-login-in-in-app-purchase-sandbox-account).